# Pass queried email to "mailto:"

Tags: javascript

I am working on a dynamic query system. Simply, the user makes search with different parameters and the query results are dynamically changing based on these parameters.I am showing the results in a table. One option of the system is showing documents (pdfs). When the user clicks the document name, pdf file is opened.Following code works fine for the purpose.

```
function displayResults_document(pElmt) {
var table = pElmt.append("table").attr("class", "result-table");
var tr = table.append("tr").attr("id", "row1");
    // Document Name
    tr.append("td").append("h4").append("a").attr("href", function (d) {
                if (d.attributes.link) {
                    return d.attributes.link;
                } else {
                    return "#";
                }
            })
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.attributes.name;
            });
}
```

One of the other results of the query are emails. What I want is, when the user clicks the email address, outlook (or other email app) opens with the clicked address to send the email. Here is what I did up to now (similar the code above). I tried the selected email address by replacing `%s`

```
function displayResults_email(pElmt) {
var table = pElmt.append("table").attr("class", "result-table");
var tr = table.append("tr").attr("id", "row1");
    //Email Queried List
    tr.append("td").append("h4").append("a").attr("href", function(d) {
        var prefix = "mailto:%s";
        var query_results = d.attributes.email1;
        var end_result = prefix.replace("%s", query_results);
        return end_result;
    }).text(function (d){
        return d.attributes.email1;
    });
}
```

With the code above, it logs `mailto:undefined` I think I need to pass the variable as global or sth? Although my several trials, I couldn't do that.. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, sometimes a short break and a little fresh air helps to see small mistakes.. Following code solves my problem. Hope someone else benefits also..

```
function displayResults_email(pElmt) {
var table = pElmt.append("table").attr("class", "result-table");
var tr = table.append("tr").attr("id", "row1");
    // Email
    tr.append("td").append("h4").append("a").attr("href", function (d) {
                var prefix = "mailto:%s";
                var query_result = d.attributes.email1;
                var end_result = prefix.replace("%s", query_result);
                return end_result;
            }).text(function (d) {
                return d.attributes.email1;
            });
}
```